# How to use variable cell value in api query

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

I am a newbie with VBA and would like to perfect the last step in a complex spreadsheet. I hope someone can help me.

I need to convert EUR to USD based on historical dates which are to be found in adjacent cells and I need to do this for an entire column.

My query works fine with a fixed date inserted, no variable. How can I run this type of query with VBA for each row while inserting the appropriate variable date?

I have column B with date, column R with a modified date and column S with EUR value.

My target cell would be something like the below formula, where I have inserted in brackets where I need the variables applied to the search query. (dates).
Basically: If B5 is empty- do nothing, if R5(modified date) is empty- use B5 date for search, or else use R5 date for search

```
=IF( B5="",  "", IF(R5="",[QUERY DATE VALUE IS B5] S5*XCH!B2, [QUERY DATE VALUE IS R5] B5*XCH!B2))
```

Sorry if I am not very technical here, thus I'm including all the info I have.

My working query (not VBA) is set up like this: (Note Date in query)
APPLIED STEPS:

Source: `= Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://www.x-rates.com/historical/?from=EUR&amount=1&date=2018-07-01"))`

Navigation: `= Source{0}[Data]`

Changed Type: `= Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data,{{"Euro", type text}, {"1.00 EUR", type number}, {"inv. 1.00 EUR", type number}})`

Removed Bottom Rows: `= Table.RemoveLastN(#"Changed Type",8)`

For example, in my target cell, the simple formula below works by using the fixed date inserted into the query (not the appropriate date).

```
=IF( B5="",  "", IF(R5="", S5*XCH!B2, S5*XCH!B2))
```

Now, how do I get the above results for each cell BUT based on the values in R5 and S5 respectively?

Is this even possible to run VBA for each single cell in a column? All data is currently imported via a Macro from another worksheet. No user input.

So I would either use a macro- button to update all values on click, or use VBA to update the EUR value the moment data is imported.

I greatly appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Are my eyes so bad that `..., S5*XCH!B2, S5*XCH!B2` isn't identical? What am I missing?

Comment: You need a User Defined Function (UDF) to take the values and return the result. You can then insert the function against each row in your results

Comment: @Jeeped looks like the second parameter should be `S5*XCH!R5`

Comment: Yes that part of the formula is identical... (same cell with euro value multiplied by the cell containing the exchange rate)  The only thing that will change in that calculation is the historical date on which the exchange rate must be queried... in fact, the part I have no idea how to do.